# MutableList<object> variable in method (Kotlin)

Tags: android, list, kotlin

is there any way to generate an array of multiple objects?

i want something like this:

```
doSomething(MutableList<String>) or doSomething(MutableList<Int>) 
fun doSomething(list : MutableList<VariableObject>){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what generics are for,

```
fun <T> doSomething(list: MutableList<T>) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Any

```
 fun doSomething(list: MutableList<Any>) {
    val value = list[0]
    when (value) {
        is String -> {
        }
        is Int ->{}
        is yourcustomclass->{}
    }
}
```